# shorter url with php

Tags: php

I've seen it before and I have no clue how to do it or what to look for on google to find it.
Basically I'd like to know how to get these shortened urls to work, what i mean is for example

this: http://website.com/index.php?id=666
turned into this: http://website.com/666

Is there some way to do this through php or do people actually go around making maps for each id?

thanks

Comment: google `mod_rewrite` or `URL Rewrite`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Hi there depends what server you are on but if you are using a server with apache that has mod rewrite you can use a htaccess rule.

So an example would be:

first create a .htaccess file then paste in the following content:

```
RewriteEngine on

RewriteRule ^([^/\.]+)?$ index.php?id=$1 [L]
```

Comment: have edited my answer with the code you need to use here is a usefull bit of info: http://zenverse.net/seo-friendly-urls-with-htaccess/ but you can get more by reading up but it's al done using regular expressions.... hope this helps!